# Is there a way to remove spaces getting counted as a character?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to coding and I want to make a program which counts the characters in a text file, but I want it to just count the letters and other symbols but the spaces in-between each word is getting recognized as a character, is there a way to make it so it doesn't count spaces as a character?

My code so far:

```
        label2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Length.ToString();
```

Comment: You can look into using `.Count()` on the string and use the lambda expression to filter out space chars

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608691/length-of-string-without-spaces-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Length of string WITHOUT spaces (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608691/length-of-string-without-spaces-c)

Answer (score 0):

This code has been taken from Yonatan's link : [Length of string WITHOUT space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608691/length-of-string-without-spaces-c)

```
label2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Count(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToString();
```

Comment: @corzan:       From next time, pls google your problem or search it on StackOverflow and prevent asking questions that are previously asked.

Comment: I tried using your solution but it doesn't work since I can't convert a int to string.

Comment: @corzan:       Pls try my updated code and revert for any errors.(Wish there are none :))

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple ways

1) By Regular Expression

```
Regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, @"\s+", "").Length
```

2) Using LINQ

```
label2.Text  = richTextBox1.Text.Where(s => s != ' ').ToArray<char>().Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me:

```
label2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "").Length.ToString();
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ohdps)